# Eclipse Kura installation on RPi 3 failed with "could not bind a reference or component"

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, kura

I am using RPi 3 + Raspbian 2017-11-29.
I want to do a Hello world on Kura. I installed Kura from [raspberry-pi-quick-start.html](https://eclipse.github.io/kura/intro/raspberry-pi-quick-start.html), everything OK on the web UI, the localhost/kura is available.
I want to add the greenhouse demo from [java/tutorial](https://iot.eclipse.org/java/tutorial/) but without success.
I checked the logs found on RPi at: /var/log/kura-console.log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2018-02-01 15:42:24.516
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component         
org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration.CloudConfigurationHandler. The 
reference is: Reference[name = CloudService, interface = o$

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2018-02-01 15:42:25.730
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component 
org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment.hook.DeploymentHookManager. The 
reference is: Reference[name = DeploymentHook, interface = o$

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2018-02-01 15:42:59.813
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component 
org.eclipse.kura.net.admin.NetworkConfigurationService. The reference 
is: Reference[name = ModemManagerService, interface = o$
Kura Started (pid=367) ...
!SESSION 2018-02-01 15:44:44.605 --------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_151
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=arm, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -configuration /tmp/.kura/configuration -console 5002 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2018-02-01 15:45:12.656
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component 
org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration.CloudConfigurationHandler. The 
reference is: Reference[name = CloudService, interface = o$

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2018-02-01 15:45:15.950
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component 
org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment.hook.DeploymentHookManager. The 
reference is: Reference[name = DeploymentHook, interface = o$

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2018-02-01 15:45:38.340
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component 
org.eclipse.kura.net.admin.NetworkConfigurationService. The reference 
is: Reference[name = ModemManagerService, interface = o$

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2018-02-01 15:47:39.989
!MESSAGE [SCR] Enabling components of bundle org.eclipse.kura.web2 did 
not complete in 60000 ms
```

Any ideas on what's the problem here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The greenhouse demo is based on an older version of Kura (v1.3.0). It will not work if you are using a newer version of Kura. You can find several example projects in the Kura Github repo: https://github.com/eclipse/kura/tree/develop/kura/examples